# How can I force a specific device to re-authenticate?

Tags: authentication, wifi

I gave out my home router Wi-Fi password to a guest who wanted to surf the internet while staying at home. I am almost sure that he checked the *"remember password"* option on his device so, from now on, in future visits he can potentially access my network resources (including shared folders) whenever he is within range.

At that time I didn't have an isolated guest network enabled. Now I do.

I would like to deauth his device or revoke his credentials so that on future visits he is forced to re-authenticate using the guest network instead.

How can I do it without having to change my password or resetting my router?

Comment: Your options can vary greatly depending on the router you have, can you be more specific about what your using?

Comment: Changing your password would be best, what if he wrote the password down and uses it on multiple devices? MAC whitelisting / blacklisting comes to mind, though it's not a solid defence as it's trivial to spoof. If you have a high end router, it may support some sort of 2FA which would prevent connections.

Comment: Uh, ask him? You can see if he is using the non-guest network, so just ask him to use the guest network and give him the new password ...

Comment: @schroeder That wouldn't solve the problem, since as long as my password is stored in his device he can switch back from the guest network to my network. I think routers nowadays provide us network administrators with tools to avoid direct confrontation with users. That's the whole point of my question. Merry Christmas!

Comment: Another person asked *which* router you are using so that we can help you narrow in on the specific tools ... I am certainly not aware of any such tool (aside from MAC filtering)

Comment: @schroeder and I won't disclose that...

Comment: I can't imagine why. There is literally no reason not to. The answer to your question is then found in your router's manual.

Comment: @schroeder *"There is literally no reason not to"* not even privacy/opsec? So I asked this question to better protect my home network, and one month later I'm put on hold...*sigh

Comment: You are rejecting all of our answers and insisting that there must be "tools nowadays". If there are, then they are part of your router's toolset. You won't tell us what the router is to even know if something like MAC filtering is possible, so, go read the manual. Ultimately, that's the answer.

Comment: And no, privacy/opsec is not a reason. No privacy or opsec is risked by disclosing. And no, you are *not* asking to protect your network, you are asking to avoid a conversation with your guest (one who you expect to violate your request to switch networks).

Comment: @schroeder *"You are rejecting all of our answers"* I didn't reject any answer, just for the record...

Comment: You won't change your password, you won't reset your router's SSID, and you won't talk to the guest. 3 things we have suggested.

Comment: @schroeder Those are the initial premises of my question...

Comment: Which leaves you with the specific capabilities of your router. Which you won't disclose, which means you need to read your router's manual. No need to make it personal. We simply cannot answer you with your constraints.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to simply change the Wi-Fi SSID password. You could even change the SSID itself.

You could add their MAC address to a block list if you know it, that will also block them but it isn't 100% effective as they *could* change their MAC address in a number of ways. The easiest being to use a different Wi-Fi card.